# Fill image to parent button Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Hello I'm new to Flutter and I just start learning, I'm currently facing this problem that I added photo to my button and I want it to fit to the whole button so if I create another one there would be no space between them. Which now leave the space between buttons. I tried fit: BoxFit.fill and height: double.infinity but it doesn't work for me. Thank you in advance for any clue :)

```
Expanded buildKey(key, soundNumber) {
    return Expanded(
      child: TextButton(
        onPressed: () {
          playSound(soundNumber);
        },
        child: Image.asset(
          key,
          height: double.infinity,
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              buildKey('images/1.png', 1),
              buildKey('images/2.png', 2),
              buildKey('images/1.png', 3),
              buildKey('images/2.png', 4),
              buildKey('images/1.png', 5),
              buildKey('images/2.png', 6),
              buildKey('images/1.png', 7),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `GestureDetector` instead of `TextButton`

```
GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              playSound(soundNumber);
            },
            child: Image.asset(
              key,
              height: double.infinity,
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much! :)